# MySQL where clause to get next week events

Tags: php, mysql

My table contains `event_start` date and `event_end` date.

I'm confused how to get the next week events. The following variables has the next week start date and end date.

```
$day = date('w');
$next_week_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.(7-$day).' days'));
$next_week_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.(7+(6-$day)).' days'));
```

I would like to get the events that are active on next week.

This is what i have now.  Here `EVENT_SCHEDULE` is the table name and `event_date` is the event start date.

```
$where .= " AND ( ( " . EVENT_SCHEDULE . ".event_date >= '" . $next_week_start . "' AND " . EVENT_SCHEDULE . ".event_date <= '" . $next_week_end . "' ) OR ( " . EVENT_SCHEDULE . ".event_enddate >= '" . $next_week_start . "' AND " . EVENT_SCHEDULE . ".event_enddate <= '" . $next_week_end . "' ) ) ";
```

Can some one help me with `where` clause of the query?

Comment: Could you make an sql-fiddle with some sample data, and tell us what you get now and what you are expecting?

Comment: The where clause  shows that your events have start and end dates so I assume you need all events that are partially or whole within the selected week. You might want to edit your question

Comment: @Naruto Thanks for the tip. Next time, i'll do that

Comment: @DobromirVelev Your answer works fine.. :)

Comment: About the dates calculation - I have never actually seen it done like that although it works. However  to avoid time difference between the PHP server and the MySQL server you might consider doing all the date calculation in MySQL - I'll amend my answer to show how it is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the start and the end variables are correctly calculated
you should be able to use

```
        $where .= "AND (" . 
EVENT_SCHEDULE . ".event_date <= '".$next_week_end."' AND " . 
EVENT_SCHEDULE . ".event_enddate >='" . $next_week_start."') ";
```

Here is the same code but with the date calculations done on the MySQL server - I am assuming the week is Monday to Sunday

```
$where .= "AND (" . 
    EVENT_SCHEDULE . ".event_date <= date(Now()+interval 14-date_format(Now(),'%w') day) AND " . 
    EVENT_SCHEDULE . ".event_enddate >= date(Now()+interval 8-date_format(Now(),'%w') day)) ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what datatype your field event_date has, but if it's an Unix-time you should not create a human readable time-string, but an unix timestamp instead. But this depends on your database scheme. you have not provided the actual problem. The where clause you provided looks good to me.

Comment: the where clause will not catch events that have started before the start of the week and are active after the end, so I assume that is his problem

Comment: indeed, haven't thought of that!